# Hoechst red and blue spectra - what does the red emission tell us?

Tags: staining

I understand that the blue spectrum is emitted when Hoechst 33342 binds to nuclear DNA. But what exactly is the red spectrum telling us?

I read that the red spectrum can be indicative of apoptosis, cellular complexity, or a proxy for cytoplasmic content.

What exactly is the red spectrum indicative of in terms of the cellular context?

edit**

Sorry for not getting back to this question sooner. I found the answer in this paper:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022175995002146#

Apparently condensed chromatin during apoptosis causes hoechst to shift to a red spectrum.

Comment: There are several Höchst dyes, you might want to clarify which you are talking about.

Comment: I am talking about Hoechst 33342 specifically.

Comment: could you provide a link or reference about the function of the dye as "indicative of apoptosis, cellular complexity, or a proxy for cytoplasmic content". I'm quite interested! I know that some dyes such as CyTRAK orange that stains both nucleus and cytoplasm with cytoplasm being a lighter orange colour than the nucleus but the described hoechst 33342 property is new to me, so I would be interested in any links/references you could provide supporting your question!

Comment: This question lacks evidence for the main claim made!

Comment: That's a problem but it doesn't warrant sniping the question down immediately like this. Give the asker some time to edit the question and explain where he made such a claim before putting him through a tedious reopen procedure. If he doesn't respond within the next days, close it down.

Comment: Looking at the hoechst red spectrum is a pretty common practice in flow cytometry (examining the side population for example). It's not some random claim I made. Anyways, I found the answer in a paper. I updated the main question.